# How to add custom keyboard in Lubuntu

Tags: keyboard, lubuntu

I want to add myanmar keyboard for Lubuntu 14.04. But, after installed it didn't shown up in iBus. How to solve? Please. sorry for my bad english.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/ibus-myanmar/

Comment: https://github.com/happyman/myanmar-learn/tree/master/ibus-keyboard-layout/ibus-myanmar-read-only

Comment: I've tried those. But it didn't work for me. I can't find Burmese or Myanmar in iBus. Edit : Thanks for reply. Did xkb work in Lubuntu ?

Comment: are Burmese and Myanmar the same by any chance ? In terms of font and form.

Comment: Because on my Ubuntu Mate there IS Burmese language keyboard layout

Comment: Found this: https://code.google.com/p/myanmar-xkb-keyboard-ubuntu/source/checkout ... maybe it will help you

Answer (score 0):

I think you add language myanmar  you want in setting language, after you restart computer, and you show ibus and config keyboard you want.